# randomly select a 200x200 square inside an image in python

Tags: python, image-processing, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I am using python to work on my project in image processing. Suppose I got a very large image ( 100000 x 100000), and I need to randomly select a 200 x 200 square from this large image. Are there any easy way to do this job? Please share some light with me. Thank you

----------------------------- EDIT ------------------------------------

Sorry I don't think it is 100000 x 100000, but the resolution of images are in 1 km and 2km. I am having trouble with selecting the area of 200 x 200.

Comment: How is the image stored in memory? As a matrix or as a sequence of bytes?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? (a) selecting a random 200x200 location, (b) extracting a given square from your large image, or (c) handling a 10 billion pixel image?

Comment: That's a very large image... either an *insane amount* of memory (that's 4*10^5*10^5 = 4*10^10 = 40 GIGABYTES for 4bytes/pixel!) and a *very very fast* disk array and a *fair bit* of time or use an image format that can be sectionalized? (e.g. individual files or can be mmap'ed into) I have a feeling the latter would be a good choice... and I bet there are already specialized solutions that do as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you convert to binary PPM format, then there should be an easy way to seek to the appropriate offsets - it's not compressed, so there should be simple relationships.

So pick two random numbers between 0 and 100000-200-1, and go to town.

(I'm assuming you don't have a system with 10's of gigabytes of RAM)